# How to create directories in AWS S3 using Apache NiFi putS3Object

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I have a working config to push files from a directory on my server to an S3 bucket. NiFi is running on a different server so I have a getSFTP. The source files have subfolders my putS3Object current config does not support and jams all of the files at the root level of the S3 bucket. I know there's a way to get putS3Object to create directories using defined folders. The ObjectKey by default is set to `${filename}`. If set to say, `my/directory/${filename}`, it creates two folders, `my` and the subfolder `directory`, and puts the files inside. However, I do NOT know what to set for the object key to replicate the file(s) source directories.

Comment: Please share some code so the community can offer better help.

Comment: There is no code associated with this. It is configured via GUI

Comment: Have you tried `${absolute.path}` or  `${path}`?

Comment: That seems to mostly work.${path} created the absolute path anyways so no difference notice between the two. Would you happen to know the answer to my question that's commented below on Ashaman's answer?

Comment: Is it possible that the string you are generating as a path for S3 is wrong? Something like `s3://my-bucket//folder1/folder2//file-name.txt` would generate in S3 a couple of blank folders, one on the root of the bucket and another one just before the file. This answer might give you some extra clues: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120135

Comment: I figured it out and basically it's that. The path set that the getSFTP is pulling from is "/home/user/mydir" which created that initial blank dir and dir right before each actual file. Coupled with the ObjectKey setting in the putS3Object processor which was ${path}/${filename}, which created the / between files and parent folders. I removed that / so it's just ${path}${filename} which took care of the trailing empty dirs. For the root dirs, the entry point was my user home dir, so simply indicated the path from there rather than the absolute path.

Comment: So before I would do /home/user/dir, but changed just to dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `${path}/${filename}` based on [this](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) in the documentation:

> Keeping with the example of a file that is picked up from a local file system, the FlowFile would have an attribute called **filename** that reflected the name of the file on the file system. Additionally, the FlowFile will have a **path** attribute that reflects the directory on the file system that this file lived in.

Comment: That seems to do it. However, it was ${path}/${filename} instead. Would you happen to know why it would create a blank root folder?
If I am copying /home/user/files, it'll create an empty folder and home as a subfolder with the other stuff inside.

Comment: Urgh, that was a typo on my part, I'll fix that.  Can you temporarily enable CloudTrail logs for monitoring data requests (there's a fee associated), so we can see exactly what data is being passed to S3, unless you can see that in the logs for NiFi.

Comment: I can't share the logs but CloudTrail does not reveal any API calls to S3, only logins and some EC2 actions. I actually have two empty directories. The first empty, nameless root directory, and it creates all the subfolders fine, but then creates an empty dir right before the files themselves.
Ex. /(empty)/dir/dir/dir/(empty)/files

Comment: You probably don't have CloudTrail data events enabled, that is why you are not seeing the S3 traffic.

Comment: No, I have CloudTrail enabled. Functionality may be limited on this account however. Unfortunately, I'm not able to enable it specifically for S3.

Comment: Let's try another method to find the path that NiFi is providing S3.  In the NiFi configuration for PutS3Object, add a custom metadata (i.e. in the Dynamic Properties section of the configuration), e.g. TestKey with the value of ${path}/${filename}.  Once the object has been added to S3, view its metadata in the S3 console so we can determine exactly what key NiFi is passing to S3.  We can then troubleshoot from there.

Comment: I got it. See the comment thread attached to the question. It came down to the forward slashes when specifying directories basically.

Comment: but what about if you have a parameter such a #{succes_directory} ?